# Why doesn't the nth-child selector get overwritten by another?

Tags: html, css

I have set up the following example: http://jsfiddle.net/SXEty/

```
<style>
table td, th { padding: 8px; text-align: left; }
table td:nth-child(1) { color: red; }
table td { color: blue }
</style>
...
<table>
    <tr><th>Name</th><th>Age</th><th>City</th></tr>
    <tr><td>Bob</td><td>27</td><td>Los Angeles</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Charlie</td><td>34</td><td>San Diego</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Daniel</td><td>41</td><td>San Francisco</td></tr>
</table>
```

I'm curious why the first column is colored as red instead of blue.

In my CSS, I set every first  child to color "red". But then my next line of CSS sets every  element to color "blue". Wouldn't the second line of CSS (color: blue) override the previous line (color: red)?  Or is it that the nth-child property has precedence? If it does have precedence, is this true for all browsers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `table td:nth-child(1)` is a more specific selector, it will have precedence over `table td` even if the latter is declared later.

What's interesting is if you target a parent ID with `table td`, everything will turn blue - even if `table td:nth-child(1)` is declared later in the CSS sheet.

[image]
http://jsfiddle.net/mLrAf/2/

Answer (score 5):

Because `td:nth-child(1)` is more specific than just `td`.

There's a great overview of CSS specificity with a Star Wars theme that I suggest

http://www.stuffandnonsense.co.uk/archives/css_specificity_wars.html

[image]